# .Min() and .Max() functions not working during data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I am trying to produce a graph and with the x axis and y axis display ranges defined by the calculated data in my c# code. I wanted to set the x axis range at 50 centered at a particular value (SpotValue), and I wanted to set the y axis range to be between the min and the max of the data the lineseries is displaying.

I have used the same approach for binding the axis ranges but for some reason it is working for the x axis but not the y axis. What's really strange is that if I replace the `CallDeltaVector.Min()` and `CallDeltaVector.Max()` with numbers, the graph picks up the correct y axis range.

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working with the `.Min()` and `.Max()` functions. I tried searching thoroughly and did not find a similar issue anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following XAML

```
    <charting:Chart 
        x:Name="CallDeltaGraph" Title="Call Delta" 
        Background="Black" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" 
        FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke" 
        BorderThickness="3" Width="350" Height="350" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="786,82,0,0">
            <charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <charting:Chart.Axes>
                <charting:LinearAxis 
                    x:Name="CallDeltaGraphXAxis" 
                    Orientation="X" Minimum="{Binding Path=Key}" 
                    Maximum="{Binding Path=Value}" ShowGridLines="True"/>
                <charting:LinearAxis 
                    x:Name="CallDeltaGraphYAxis"  
                    Orientation="Y" Minimum="{Binding Path=Key}" 
                    Maximum="{Binding Path=Value}" ShowGridLines="True" />
            </charting:Chart.Axes>
            <charting:Chart.Series>
                <charting:LineSeries 
                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" 
                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
            </charting:Chart.Series>
        </charting:Chart>
```

and I have the following c# code:

```
    KeyValuePair<double, double>[] XRange = new KeyValuePair<double, double>[1];
    XRange[0] = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(Math.Floor(SpotPrice) - 25, Math.Ceiling(SpotPrice) + 25);
    CallDeltaGraphXAxis.DataContext = XRange;

    KeyValuePair<double, double>[] CallDeltaYRange = new KeyValuePair<double, double>[1];
    CallDeltaYRange[0] = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(CallDeltaVector.Min(), CallDeltaVector.Max());
    CallDeltaGraphYAxis.DataContext = CallDeltaYRange;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
KeyValuePair<double, double>[] CallDeltaYRange = new KeyValuePair<double, double>[1];
    CallDeltaYRange[0] = new KeyValuePair<double, double>(CallDeltaVector.Min(), CallDeltaVector.Max());
    CallDeltaGraphYAxis.DataContext = CallDeltaYRange;
```

to instead create an instance of this class...

```
    CallDeltaYRangeInfo cvRange = new CallDeltaYRangeInfo{Ymax = CallDeltaVector.Max(), Ymin = CallDeltaVector.Min()};
```

Where the class is defined like...

```
public class CallDeltaYRangeInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _yMin;
    public double Ymin
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _yMin; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (Math.Abs(value - _yMin) > 1e-6)
            {
                _yMin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Ymin");
            }
        }
    }
    private double _yMax;
    public double Ymax
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _yMax; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (Math.Abs(value - _yMax) > 1e-6)
            {
                _yMax = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Ymax");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

... then you can assign CallDeltaGraphYAxis.DataContext to that instance and you will see a better result.

```
      <charting:LinearAxis x:Name="CallDeltaGraphYAxis"  Orientation="Y" Minimum="{Binding Ymin}" Maximum="{Binding Ymax}"  ShowGridLines="True" />
```

Comment: @Noctis, it wasn't a lift.  Composition and getting a clean compile takes a longer time.

Comment: Thank you guys soooooo much! Really really appreciate it :) I'll try this out first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm ... very puzzling your code ... First of all, you use a `KeyValuePair<double, double>` in order to then just use it as `key`- `value`, but those are really `Min` and `Max`, so it's misleading.

Second, you have this:

```
Minimum="{Binding Path=Key}" Maximum="{Binding Path=Value}"
```

So the binding looks for a property called `Key` and one called `Value`, but you don't have them ... what you have are `key` and `value` on your `KeyValuePair`.

I guess you can bind to the `KeyValuePair` and give it the `key` or `value` as relative path, something along:

```
 <Binding  ElementName=your_object, Path=key_or_value>
```

or MUCH BETTER: have a property called `MinVal`, one called `MaxVal`, and bind to them ...